# Isn't there a standard jQuery pop-up menu component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, widget

I'd expect a right-click-context-menu-style pop-up menu to be a part of jQuery UI. But apparently it isn't. What's the de-facto standard out there? Or is everybody just rolling out their own ones?

[Example](http://twitpic.com/17bve8/full)

Comment: Are you talking about a right-click context menu or more like a dialog / alert window ?

Comment: A context menu. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for dialog

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Or jQuery Impromptu http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php